# How to convert audios without installing ffmpeg

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, converters, ffmpeg-php

I'm using a shared hosting. I need **convert mp3 files to ogg files** on my host, I asked its admins to install `FFMpeg` but they didn't do that! Is it possible **convert mp3 to ogg/ogg to mp3** on my host by php? If yes please get me `code examples` or something!

Comment: You will need to install something. I doubt there are pure php mp3 decoder and vorbis encoders.

Comment: @szatmary I don't mean `pure php`, I need library or something to do that for me but I tried `php-ffmpeg` library but it needs `FFMpeg` **installed** on server!

Comment: @MohammadHoodaji Host somewhere else.  VPS is so cheap these days... probably as cheap as your shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "install" `ffmpeg`. No need for root/super user/admin to interveine. Just download and execute:

- [Linux](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)
- [Windows & macOS](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Your OS is unknown, but for example on Linux you would download the archive to your server, extract the archive, and execute the `ffmpeg` file. You can move it to `~/bin`, which is likely in your `PATH`, and then you can run `ffmpeg` from any directory (but you may have to re-login).